# Who are these Blizzard characters?

Tags: character-identification, warcraft, diablo, starcraft

I came across [this article](http://2p.com/36600890_1/Matthew-Cooper-Blizzard-Has-a-List-of-200-plus-Characters-for-HotS-by-Aaron.htm) that has an image with a bunch of Blizzard characters.

[image: 71 Blizzard characters]

*Please note  this a editted(poorly) version that I made to group the characters together better. Click to enlarge.

These are the ones I know. D behind a charcter stands for [Diablo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_(series)), W for [Warcraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warcraft), S for [Starcraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft), and B for [Blizzard Classic](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/games/legacy/).

1. Abuthar, S
2. Anub'arak, W
3. Arthas Menethil, W
4. Azmodan, D
5. Falstad Wildhammer, W
6. ETC, W
7. Diablo, D
8. Chen Stormstout, W
9. Brightwing, D
10. Gazlowe, W
11. Illidan Stormrage, W
12. Jaina Proudmore, W
13. Sarah Kerrigan, S
14. Li Li Stormstout, W
15. Nova, S
16. Nazeebo, W
17. Murky, W
18. Muradin Bronzebeard, W
19. Malfurion Stormrage, W
20. Jim Raynor, S
21. Rehgar Earthfury, W
22. Sgt. Hammer, S
23. Sonya, D
24. Stiches, W
25. Tychus Findlay, S
26. Thrall, W
27. Lost Vikings, B
28. Tassadar, S
29. Sylvanas Windrunner, W
30. Tyrael, D
31. Tyrande Whisperwind, W
32. Unther Lightbring, W
33. Valla, D
34. Zagara, S
35. ???, W (per @ShadyBaby - Velen, W)
36. Gabriel Tosh, S
37. ????, ? (per @ShadyBaby - Fenix, S)
38. Kael'thas Sunstrider, W
39. Zeratul, S
40. Selendis, S
41. ???, ? (per @ShadyBaby - Imperius, D)
42. Malthael, D
43. ???, ? (per @ShadyBaby - Blackhand, W)
44. Some Orc, W (per @ShadyBaby -  Grommash Hellscream, W)
45. ???, D? (per Misha Rosnach - Baal, D)
46. Shadow of Diablo?, D? (per @ShadyBaby- Mephisto, D)
47. The Butcher, D
48. Rexxar, D
49. Deathwing, W
50. Artanis, S
51. ???, ?? (per Misha Rosnach - Alexei Stukov, S)
52. ???, ?? (per Misha Rosnach - Dehaka, S)
53. Looks like maybe Warcraft (per @ShadyBaby - Kel'Thuzad, W)
54. ????, ?  (per @ShadyBaby - Kil'jaeden, W)
55. ????, ? (per @ShadyBaby - Archimonde, W)
56. Deckard Cain, D
57. Anduin Wrynn, W (per Misha Rosnach actually - Valerian Mengsk, S)
58. ???, ?? (per @ShadyBaby - Maive Shadowsong, W)
59. ???, D? (per @ShadyBaby - Belial, D)
60. Skeleton King Leoric, D
61. ???, ?? (per Misha Rosnach - Arcturus Mengsk, S)
62. ???, ?? (per @ShadyBaby - Mannoroth, W)
63. Some Zerg Maybe, S?
64. Cydaea, D
65. ???, W (per @ShadyBaby - Varian Wrynn, W)
66. Some Troll, W (per @ShadyBaby -  Vol'jin, W)
67. Gul'dan, W
68. Magda, D
69. Garrosh Hellscream, W
70. Auriel, D
71. ???, ?? (per @ShadyBaby - Lilith, D)

Comment: May I suggest that the post be edited to add the ones that have now been identified, making it easier to see who is still yet to be identified. I just tried but it was rejected on the grounds that I should post them as an answer or comment instead (which has already been done.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

35: [Velen](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Velen) (W)

37: [Fenix](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Fenix) (S)

41: [Imperius](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Imperius) (D)

43: [Blackhand](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Blackhand) (W)

44: [Grommash Hellscream](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Grommash_Hellscream) (W) - http://wow.gamepedia.com/Grommash_Hellscream
Grommash is a green orc, however in the alternative time line of WoD, he is red.

46: [Mephisto](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Mephisto) (D)

53: [Kel'Thuzad](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=15990/kelthuzad) (W)

54: [Kil'jaeden](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Kil'jaeden) (W)

55: [Archimonde](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=91331/archimonde) (W)

58: [Maive Shadowsong](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Maiev_Shadowsong) (W) 
I'm 95% certain with this one, however all Warden's wear this helm so it would be almost impossible to tell from that icon. There is only one other Warden of significance I can think of, the one who plays a role in WoD, however her name has escaped me.

59: [Belial](http://www.diablowiki.net/Belial) (D)

62: [Mannoroth](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Mannoroth) (W)

65: [Varian Wrynn](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Varian_Wrynn) (W) 
King of Stormwind

66: [Vol'jin](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Vol'jin) (W) 
Leader of the Darkspear trolls and the Warchief of the Horde following Garrosh's fall.

71: [Lilith](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Lilith) (D)

In regards to the article referenced, I'm not sure how accurate the information is due to characters such as Cho'Gal and [Greymane](http://heroesofthestorm.gamepedia.com/Greymane) not being on the list (that I can see.) If you read the [interview](http://www.redbull.com/us/en/esports/stories/1331750664574/senior-game-designer-matthew-cooper-talks-heroes) referenced at the bottom of the article, the image you have used from the article is the only one not taken from the original interview write-up. Whilst I have no doubt Blizzard had many heroes planned, they may not be the one's on this list.

Comment: Yeah I know the List isn't accurate as for as each shown character's HOTS potential. That's why I just said, "here are a bunch of Blizzard characters, who are they?" and didn't mention HOTS.

Answer (score 5):

45: [Baal](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Baal), D

51: [Alexei Stukov](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Alexei_Stukov), S

52: [Dehaka](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Dehaka), S

61: [Arcturus Mengsk](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Arcturus_Mengsk), S

57: I believe it is actually Arcturus' son,[Valerian Mengsk](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Valerian_Mengsk), S.  Anduin Wrynn's hair and collar are slightly different.

Comment: 57 is Valerian Mengsk

Comment: They really do look a lot alike from the collar up though.

Comment: Anduin's Hairstyle is always symmetrical and the collar is Valerian's

Comment: Yeah, the collar does seem to lean towards Valerian, although in some images Wrynn has a parted collar. Just doesn't feel like Wrynn. I think I'll make that part of the answer a bit more assertive.

Answer (score 2):

After some more research I have found out that #63 is [The Overmind](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Overmind) , S.

[image: overmind]

Comment: Nice! That one was bothering me a lot.