# Identify Halloween / Supernatural themed movies in this picture

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

**Original Title: Name that Movie: Halloween Theme.**

Cheaters may prosper, but they also are the ones who go to the special place in Hell.

> A level they reserve for child molesters and people who talk during movies.

[image: ID Part 1]

[image: ID Part 2]

[image: ID Part 3]

[image: ID Part 4]

Comment: Insert *We Hate FUN!* trope here.

Comment: I love fun. But surely we could have done this on the blog, or in chat, or even on meta? Not on the main site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't honestly asking for identification of these films. It's a game - a fun game, but still a game. And really only fun for a few people for about 10 minutes. Then it's just day specific clutter.

Comment: This is very much in line with similar picture identification questions we've had before, whether or not it's for a game. It presents a clear, specific visual artifact requesting list of supernatural SFF media.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107467/what-are-the-names-of-all-the-sci-fi-vessels-in-this-artwork http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114861/who-are-these-blizzard-characters http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121259/who-are-these-classic-dc-characters http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117496/identify-these-retro-machines  Are just a few of such questions.

Comment: To me, the distinction between the questions linked to by @CreationEdge (which I am familiar with) are that there is some element of "I came across this image from elsewhere" and / or the images are stylized in such a way as to render some amount of obfuscation upon them, thus, the question being asked in good faith is truly one of identification, not a day themed game. But that's just me. No, I don't care enough to take it to meta and ask for arbitration on it - it's not a big deal :). But, why have close vote ability if not to vote - if nobody agrees - it won't get closed :)

Comment: @NKCampbell I didn't create this list, I was given it.

Comment: I think the origin of the list is less important than the intent behind the question. Saying 'try not to use the internet' is probably what changed the tone of the question (for me) from legitimate to 'game'. Again, nbd - just explaining my thought process (ie - I don't want to be curmudgeon!) ;)

Comment: Intent is irrelevant. If you edit out "try not to use the Internet" or ignore that part, it's just like any of the others. If posted the question and said "I found this poster of supernatural movies, but I can't ID them all." and instead of the text used here, nothing would have changed in the way the question is answered or it's on-topicness. The purpose of the question is the same.

Comment: [This](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1675/why-are-humorous-questions-off-topic) seems very relevant. I personally think this question is fine, it does seem on-topic, you are allowed to ask questions you know the answer to, the content makes something on- or off-topic, not the OP's intentions, and I think it's fun. I wouldn't want this to be a precedent-setting question, but for Halloween? Why not?

Comment: Some of those movies have no supernatural or pseudoscientific elements. Therefore the question is off topic.

Comment: @user14111 I think 29/36 is close enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Original 18 by Skooba**

1. [Friday the 13th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th_(franchise)) (1980)  <sub>Thanks to Broklynite!</sub>
2. [The Nightmare Before Christmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nightmare_Before_Christmas) (1993)
3. [Poltergeist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist_(film_series)) (1982)
4. [Psycho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psycho_(1960_film)) (1960)
5. [The Amityville Horror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amityville_Horror) (1977)
6. [Saw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_(franchise)) (2004)
7. [Scream](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117571/) (1996)
8. [Silence of the Lambs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silence_of_the_Lambs_(film)) (1991)
9. [The Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ring_(2002_film)) (2002)
10. [Twitches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitches_(film)) (2005)  <sub>Thanks to TGnat!</sub>
11. [Beetlejuice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094721/) (1988)
12. [Sweeney Todd: The Demon Barber of Fleet Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweeney_Todd:_The_Demon_Barber_of_Fleet_Street_(2007_film)) (2007)
13. [It](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099864/) (1990)
14. [Wait Until Dark](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062467/) (1967)  <sub>Thanks to Paulie_D!</sub>
15. [When a Stranger Calls](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0455857/) (2005)  <sub>Thanks *again* to Paulie_D!</sub>
16. [Ghostbusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters_(2016_film)) (2016)
17. [Casper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casper_(film)) (1995)
18. [The Munsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Munsters) (1964)

As an aside, this just goes to show you how memorable certain characters, locations, or titles can be as I had only personally seen 4 of these films myself, but was able to able to correctly identify 14 of 18 without assistance!

---

**Second Set of 18 by Howdy_McGee**

19. [The Shining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shining_(film)) (1980)
20. [The Sixth Sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sixth_Sense) (1999)
21. [Texas Chainsaw Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Texas_Chain_Saw_Massacre) (1974)
22. [Hocus Pocus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hocus_Pocus_(1993_film)) (1993)
23. [Paranormal Activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranormal_Activity) (2007)
24. [It's The Great Pumpkin, Charlie Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_the_Great_Pumpkin,_Charlie_Brown) (1966)
25. [Disturbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disturbia_(film)) (2007)
26. [Corpse Bride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpse_Bride) (2005)
27. [Cujo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cujo_(film)) (1983)
28. [Ernest Scared Stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Scared_Stupid) (1991)
29. [Carrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrie_(1976_film)) (1976)
30. [What Lies Beneath](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0161081/) (2000)  <sub>Thanks to atheaos!</sub>
31. [The Blair Witch Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blair_Witch_Project) (1999)
32. [10 Cloverfield Lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_Cloverfield_Lane) (2016)
33. [The Village](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Village_(2004_film)) (2004)
34. [The Birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birds_(film)) (1963)
35. [Shaun of The Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaun_of_the_Dead) (2004)
36. [Nosferatu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosferatu) (1922)

Comment: #1 is the ending from the original Friday the 13th movie. 13 is absolutely IT. 14 I think is The Birds but not certain.

Comment: @Broklynite I don't think Audrey Hepburn was in The Birds, but maybe she was (I'm also assuming that is Audrey Hepburn).

Comment: @Broklynite Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: #14 *Wait Until Dark*..one of my favorites

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitches_(film) 10 is twitches i think

Comment: #15 is soo familiar....Is that Camilla Belle? Lemme check

Comment: It is... *When A Stranger Calls* 2006

Comment: @Paulie_D that is two you got for me! Thank you!

Comment: @JackBNimble I haven't watched it in years but I looks very Hitchcock. I thought it might be the bit at the end when they are in the attic or something.

Comment: I reject that Ghostbusters.

Comment: @Skooba Turns out there were 18 more movies that were on the trivia game.

Comment: I've added an edit to apply for OPs updated question - the only one I didn't know was #30.

Comment: Pretty sure #30 is [What Lies Beneath](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0161081/)